# Recording selection with and without .lyr file using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute

I tried recording a selection using first `arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management` and then `'arcpy.CopyFeatures_management'` but since my input was a feature class I get an error. So, I converted my input into a .lyr and now my output is empty when I open it in Arcgis.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Temp/PyData"
shpfile = 'building_split.shp'
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_features=shpfile,
                                  out_layer="bui_lyr")
lyr = 'bui_lyr'
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(in_layer_or_view=lyr,
                                        selection_type= "SUBSET_SELECTION",
                                        where_clause= '"length" > 25')

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(in_features=lyr,
                              out_feature_class= 'res_building_25')
```

Here is my code, I guess there is a simple mistake somewhere I just began writing scripts in Python. Also, how can I perform a selection on my feature class. I guess I am not obliged to go through the creation of a .lyr file.

Edit: I did another try with a simpler code below, the test.shp file remains empty

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Temp/PyData"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("building_split.shp", "bui_lyr")
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("bui_lyr", "SUBSET_SELECTION", "length > 25")
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("bui_lyr", "C:/Temp/PyData/Test.shp")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an issue with your where clause, so nothing gets selected.

First, I'm not sure using `SUBSET_SELECTION` will work if there isn't an existing selection. Keep the default value (`NEW_SELECTION`).

Second, field names delimiters should be double quotes (they also can be omitted) for shapefiles. Also, wrapping your clause with *triple* double quotes is a good practice to ensure inner and outer quotes are matched properly (when you have multiple pairs of embedded quotes):

```
where_clause = """length > 25"""
```

See also the [arcpy.FieldDelimiters()](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/addfielddelimiters.htm) function if you want to make your query workspace-proof.

If the ultimate goal is to save your selection to a feature class, [Select](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/select.htm) will do the trick in one step. Comment regarding the where clause apply here too.

Answer (score 1):

The expression you have used in the "Select Layer by Attribute" tool is wrong. Try and use string formatting to create an expression or use the following expression:

```
exp = """"length" > 25"""
```

There are a few ways to improve your code.

1. You can use the "where clause" within the "[Make Feature Layer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-feature-layer.htm)" tool to create a layer based on your condition.
2. You can use the "[Select](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/select.htm)" tool to directly create a feature class or shapefile from a dataset by using an expression.

   > Extracts features from an input feature class or input feature layer,
   >   typically using a select or Structured Query Language (SQL) expression
   >   and stores them in an output feature class.